# Decode 8 bit wave file with pocket sphinx

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I am trying to integrate my telephony application with pocket sphinx speech recognizer. The recorded file type which I get is of the following type:

```
Input File     : '5555_9911848379__15-10-14-17-36_.wav'
Channels       : 1
Sample Rate    : 11025
Precision      : 8-bit
Duration       : 00:00:03.99 = 44000 samples ~ 299.32 CDDA sectors
File Size      : 44.0k
Bit Rate       : 88.3k
Sample Encoding: 8-bit Unsigned Integer PCM
```

but, the sample program which is given here http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx
expects 16 bit PCM audio sampled at 16000 HZ.

Is there any way I can decode the above mentioned recorded file. Or will I have to convert the above format to the 16 bit format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way I can decode the above mentioned recorded file.

No, you need 16-bit

> Or will I have to convert the above format to the 16 bit format?

Conversion will not help since information is lost already. You need 16-bit recording.

You need to make sure you are recording audio in a proper format.

Comment: The NMS APIs only give 8 bit 11025 Hz audio recordings. :(
The api calls are vceCreateFile and vceRecordMessage.

Comment: I have converted the files using sox though, using command:sox -V origninalFile.wav -t raw -s -b 16 -L -r 16000 conv.raw and it is working for now. My application is not that complex and I suppose thats why its working.

Comment: Certainly not, you can configure VCE_ENCODE_PCM8M16 or at least VCE_ENCODE_ALAW or VCE_ENCODE_PCM11M16 which are way bette than VCE_ENCODE_PCM11M8. See for details http://www.nmscommunications.com/manuals/6304-10/chap52.htm

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay for your response. I tried with the encodings VCE_ENCODE_PCM8M16 and VCE_ENCODE_PCM11M16 but the recorded file size is 0. Almost instantly VCEEVN_RECORD_DONE comes with reason 13. I am trying to dig in further. Can it be an issue with my installation of device driver? Because when I create file using VceCreateFile using those encodings, the return is success. If it would not have supported the encoding, there would have been an error.

Comment: Also, VCE_ENCODE_ALAW gives me a recorded file, but Sphinx is not able to decode it. The recognized is blank. I have used the same code which  I used for wav and raw.

Comment: You can record in ALAW and convert files to PCM using sox.

Comment: It is working. Thanks a lot for your support. I will for now go for VCE_ENCODE_ALAW to PCM and then decode. I am in touch with Dialogic guys for the reason I am still not able to get it done with other encodings.

Comment: Hi Nikolay, I figured out why it was giving error code 0XD (CTAERR_FUNCTION_NOT_AVAIL) when I was trying to record in 16 bit PCM format. We will have to add wave.rec_11_16b and similar in the configuration file. In my case the configuration file is c6565nocc.cfg

Comment: I am able to decode the recordings now, but the accuracy is very low..  :( I guess I will have to adopt to a better acoustic model or train one myself.

Comment: Accuracy issues are usually easy to solve. In order to solve accuracy issues you need to collect a set of test samples. For more information see the FAQ: http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/faq#qwhy_my_accuracy_is_poor